# swedish characters in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to do xslt transformation for the XML input. Whenever the xml input has swedish characters, xslt transformation is failing. Can someone help me how to handle this. Client needs nordic characters to be passed as it is.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="EmploymentUpdateRequests">
   <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="EmploymentUpdateRequest"
                group-by="descendant::FieldValue[@Name ='FORNAMN']">
                <xsl:sort select="descendant::FieldValue
                                  [@Name ='FORNAMN']/ValidFrom" 
                          order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Postscript**

The input looks like this:

```
<FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String"> 
  <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-08-18</ValidFrom> 
  <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2099-12-31</ValidUntil> 
  <Value>Nicoleta Geta Ã…Ã¥Ã„Ã¤Ã–Ã¶</Value> 
</FieldValue>
```

I get an error like

> Could not run 'sortXMLByValidFrom' com.wm.app.b2b.server.ServiceException: net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicError: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 76; columnNumber: 28; Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: From your input xml, you have change the  language attribute as xml:lang="sv" for swedish.

Comment: In what way does the XSLT transformation fail exactly? Do you get an error, which one exactly, from which tool (XML parser, XSLT processor)? Or is the result not as the one you expect? In that case edit your question and show minimal but complete samples of XML input, wanted output and current output to allow us to reproduce and understand the problem.

Comment: My Input is like   <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-08-18</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2099-12-31</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Nicoleta Geta Ã…Ã¥Ã„Ã¤Ã–Ã¶</Value>
    </FieldValue>                                                                                                         I get error like  
Could not run 'sortXMLByValidFrom'
com.wm.app.b2b.server.ServiceException: net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicError: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 76; columnNumber: 28; Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the input is not in UTF-8, which in turn tells us that the XSLT processor thinks the input is *supposed to* bei in UTF-8, either (1) because the in-document encoding declaration says so, or (2) because there is no in-document encoding declaration and the processor has guessed that the character encoding is UTF-8 rather than UTF-16 (these being the only two options for XML without a character encoding declaration).

In the first case the in-document encoding declaration is apparently lying and should be changed so that it tells the truth.

In the second case you should supply a correct encoding declaration.  From your statement that the input has Swedish characters and the wording of the error message, I would conjecture that the input is encoded in some variant of ISO 8859, probably ISO 8859-1, -10, or -15.

Your problem has nothing to do with XSLT and everything to do with the fact that your input is (a) not in UTF-8 or UTF-16 and (b) does not declare its character encoding.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. My input looks something like this.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. My input looks something like this.                     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <EmploymentUpdateRequests xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> <EmploymentUpdateRequest> <CompanyNo>1010</CompanyNo>   <EmploymentNo>000302</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
       <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-08-18</ValidFrom>
   <Value>Nicoleta Geta ÅåÄäÖö</Value> </FieldValue>  </Fields> </EmploymentUpdateRequest>  </EmploymentUpdateRequests>

Comment: Thanks Sperberg. I converted the incomign xml to utf-8 and xslt is not throwing any error. Thank you for the answers

Comment: I'm glad if my answer helped.  If your question has been answered, you should probably mark the answer 'accepted'; otherwise the question shows up in the Stack Overflow user interface as one still awaiting an acceptable answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will do that. I am new to this forum. I didnt know this before.